# Issues starting X in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, boot, xorg

I recently installed Ubuntu 10.10 on my old Toshiba A100 (where I've been running Windows XP with no problems for ages). The installation went fine, I can log in with my user account, but after that the screen has only the wallpaper (and the mouse is enabled). Any hints on how to troubleshoot it ?

These are the [Xorg](http://paste.ly/3s1g) and the [messages](http://paste.ly/3s1s) log files.

When booted in safe graphics mode it worked just fine. Is there a way to set that configuration as the default so I don't have to go through those menus every time I boot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Humm... it can be several things.

You can try Ctrl-Alt-F2, login and try a `dmesg` command to see if there are any errors/problems at the end.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I didn't find anything suspicious in the log files. Anyway I updated the post with links to two of them.